# Asus G75VW faulty RAM swapping

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, asus-laptop

I got a faulty RAM module and I am probably going to just replace both stock modules.
Do my new RAM modules have to be identical to the stock that I'm taking out or can I buy new ones?
The ones I'm taking out are Hynix 2 x 4 GB 1600mhz CL=11 DDR3 modules, could I swap them with HyperX Impact 1600mhz CL=9 DDR3 modules?
As I said, I plan on taking all of the stock RAM out because one is faulty

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3 be sure you purchase laptop memory instead of desktop memory there is a height and voltage  difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation: i would leave the module that works and buy another one with the same specs but only from well-known vendors like Corsair and Co.
You deal with a consumer laptop and you don't have to worry about warranty anymore. If it was a server that is in-warranty my recommendation would be somewhat different.

**The professional** straight forward answer is

- Please look up this topic in the manual, in a lot of cases, you find a list of tested and recommended memory.

The English user manual states about this topic:

- Visit an authorized service center or 
  retailer for information on memory upgrades for your Notebook PC. 
  Only purchase expansion modules from authorized retailers of this 
  Notebook PC to ensure maximum compatibility and reliability.

Source: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/G75VW/E_eManual_G75VW_VER7352.pdf?_ga=2.182440871.109408842.1512940281-1213690680.1512940281 (i am not affiliated with ASUS)

That is in deed very bad information, i would have expected better from ASUS.  Well in the end if they provide just only this instead of a compatibility list, i recommend my personal recommendation as written above ;-)